# Is there a way to build different projects (different electron-builder file) for electron

Tags: electron, electron-builder

We have a white-labeled app built with electron+angular and we want to build 3 different let's say 'flavours' of the app. Except for the UI changes in Angular we have a different electron-builder file with configurations for each project. The **problem** is that after I build the first one the next one is twice its size (as a .exe) and when I build the third one it's even bigger. It does not matter which I build first, as this is always the case.

I am building these apps with the electron-builder build command, using the --config option to pass a file with configurations.

This is the electron-builder file that I am using (with PROJECT_NAME, PROJECT_APP_ID, and PROJECT_ID changing depending on the project).

```
 "productName": "<PROJECT_NAME>",
 "appId": "<PROJECT_APP_ID>",
 "directories": {
   "output": "release/<PROJECT_ID>"
 },
 "files": [
   "**/*",
   "!**/*.ts",
   "!*.code-workspace",
   "!LICENSE.md",
   "!package.json",
   "!package-lock.json",
   "!src/",
   "!e2e/",
   "!hooks/",
   "!angular.json",
   "!_config.yml",
   "!karma.conf.js",
   "!tsconfig.json",
   "!tslint.json"
 ],
"win": {
  "icon": "dist/assets/icons/<PROJECT_ID>"
 },
"mac": {
  "icon": "dist/assets/icons/<PROJECT_ID>"
 },
"linux": {
  "icon": "dist/assets/icons/<PROJECT_ID>"
 },
}
```

Am I missing something for electron-builder? I am thinking maybe it keeps a 'cache' or something in a temporary folder and uses that to build on.
I know the question is a bit over the place, but I don't have experience with electron-builder. Any help or suggestion is welcomed.

Some details:

- I tried building it from both a windows machine and mac os.
- I am using electron-builder v22.9.1
- I have tried using different folders for the result, it still didn't work.

[**UPDATE**] In the script that i use to build these projects, if i delete the directory of the build and then continue with the others, it **will** work.